# accepting payments on website instead of in-app

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, payment

I'm working on an app/site where we have a monthly subscription fee. Is it allowed to direct users from the app to pay the subscription fees on the site instead of doing it in-app where Google would take 30% of the fees?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a web view to redirect the users to your website and let them pay over there itself. Just make sure to make the website mobile friendly.